# Invalid golang profile output format

Tags: go, alpine-linux, pprof

I've recently started to try out the pprof tools from golang. I have followed the link https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/ to add a new http server to my service so the profile is able to be accessed. 
All works fine, but when i try to generate a pdf or png output format, the text are all boxes as shown in the below image:
[image]
Is there any unicode libary that i need to install?
My service is deployed using docker alpine image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common symptom of missing fonts.

Try installing the [font-noto](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/font-noto) package:

`apk add font-noto`

For more information and hints about Alpine Linux Fonts, visit [this Alpine Linux wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Fonts) page.

Comment: you're a live saver!